# Escaping "all prerequisites" variables in Makefile

Tags: shell, quoting, make

Let's assume we have a couple of files whose names need to be quoted when used in a shell:

```bsh
echo A > 'a.$A'
echo B > 'b.$B'
```

And there is a Makefile with a rule that depends on these files:

```
all: a.$$A b.$$B
    cat $+
```

The above would work for the files with simple names but for the ones in the example it produces:

```
cat a.$A b.$B
cat: a.: No such file or directory
cat: b.: No such file or directory
```

It looks like the shell expands the `$A` and `$B` expressions to empty strings.

If I quote the variable as `cat '$+'`, then the expansion is prevented but all prerequisites are passed as a single argument:

```
cat 'a.$A b.$B'
cat: 'a.$A b.$B': No such file or directory
```

The fact that it's a single argument is sort of expected according to the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html):

> The names of all the prerequisites […], with spaces between them.

The question is, is there a way to obtain all the prerequisites as individual arguments to be able to quote them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU Make, you can use a pattern substitution to surround each word in `$+` with single quotes:

```
all: a.$$A b.$$B
        cat $(patsubst %,'%',$+)
```

This won’t work with prerequisites containing whitespace, but Make can’t really handle those anyway.